# Express Checkout Payment with different merchant

Tags: paypal

So, i have a website, each product come up with different sellers, a seller can have one or more product on the website, when a buy win a product, the buyer need to make the payment to a specify seller, with express checkout integration, they ask for credential to make the payment, but if each time the seller is different, how will i manage the credential part?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) - take a look at the different options available.